# CSS Flexbox float elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to float two elements at the right of a "figure" element using flex but it end up floating just div1 at the right of figure and div2 is moved bellow, if I make div1 and div2 narrow enough, they are floated inline at the right of figure.

This is the CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Desired Result:
[image: How should it look:]

Actual Result:

[image: How does it looks:]

Comment: There are several ways to solve this, but they depend on how flexible you are with the html.  @highdef's answer is the best if you can add a div to wrap the two divs.  If you can't you should post the exact html you are dealing with and the constraints you're operating under.

Comment: I'm altering the HTML to go with @highdef solution, I think it's the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How it works?**

First, you make a `flex-container (flexc in this case)` and apply the `display:flex` property on it which aligns the elements by default in row alignment. If you want an element to preserve its dimensions set it to `flex:0 0 auto;` else you can make use of `flex:1;` which shrinks or grows as the browser is resized.

Then to align the `contents in column (div1 and div2)` you can just wrap then in a different container and since `div isn't an inline container`, and the flex property doesn't have any effect on any other than the direct children of the flex parent, they are aligned in seperate lines.

```css
.flexc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#fig {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#d1,
#d2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexc">
  <div id="fig">Figure</div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="d1">div1</div>
    <div id="d2">div2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without altering the html:

```css
.flexc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  position:relative;
}

#fig {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#d1,
#d2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:250px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#d2{
top:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexc">
  <div id="fig">Figure</div>
    <div id="d1">div1</div>
    <div id="d2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer if you can alter the html.

Comment: I was hoping on not having to alter the HTML structure, there isn't a way to float the elements in columns? maybe using flex-direction: column

Comment: You can't make use of flex-direction column in the same parent container without an additional intermediate container like I did but if you want it without altering the html, let me see.

Comment: You can get that effect by using floats.  That's exactly how they work when your container has a width doesn't accommodate the width of all three divs.

Comment: @Flupkear Added another solution. You can make use of relative and absolute position like I have and use flex-direction:column on the main container.

Comment: @vlasits float property is ignored inside a flexbox.

Comment: True... so my recommendation is don't use flexbox.  I can't think of a situation where you'd be locked into it.  But OP hasn't fully specified all of the constraints of the situation so it's hard to guess.

Comment: @vlasits Yeah, i know. Well all solutions are there now, they can select according to their preference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll go with your original solution, adding a container for the right side elements.

Comment: @Flupkear No problem :)

Comment: You prolly ought to re-edit to reflect your original answer... for posterity.

Comment: @vlasits I have both the solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your HTML looks like, but `display: flex` is best used on the container wrapping all the elements you want aligned. Imagine it to be the largest box that you put smaller boxes inside.

[image: flexbox example]

Codepen example demonstrating this: https://codepen.io/corviday/pen/VyYdar

Following this hierarchy with `.container` as your largest box, since you want two columns, you can divide it further into two smaller boxes (`.left` in red and `.right` in blue in this case).

From there you would need to group `div1`/`div2` together to float the way you'd like, and would be the items that fill the box `.right`.

Comment: This is a good solution if you can alter the original html.  OP explained in a comment that they didn't want to do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to resolve or put div1 and div2 in one div main to drop div main

Bootstrap exemple

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      1 text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          2 text
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          3 text       
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using pure css and ideally I don't want to alter the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best layout engine to use for your use case is hinted at in your description of the problem:  Floats.

Here is a solution that doesn't require you to alter your html.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="medium-box">figure</div>
  <div class="small-box">div 1</div>
  <div class="small-box">div 2</div>
</div>

.container{
  width: 500px;
}

.medium-box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: grey;
  float:left
}

.small-box {
  float:left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/stacyvlasits/pen/aVPZbY

Comment: This is a good solution if they don't mind removing flexbox.